# How do I resolve a ClassFormatException in Play Framework 1.2.4?

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

Trying to run a Play! 1.2.4 app on OSX Snow Leopard under Java 1.6.0_33 but keep hitting this error after the login screen :-

> An unexpected error occured caused by exception ClassFormatError:
>   Invalid index 95 in LocalVariableTable in class file
>   net/sf/oval/guard/Guard

but the same code works absolutely fine under Windows 7 and Java 7 and on WinXP (sorry, Java version not known on that one).

Is this a file permissions error on my application's path, masqueraded as a Java error, or is there something else?

Comment: try upgrading your java version to java 7 and retry.

Comment: Did you *compile* the code using the same Java 6, or did you compile using Java 7 and now try to run using Java 6? `javap -v` might be of use to see what this “index 95” is about.

Comment: Can't upgrade to Java 7 on OSX Snow Leopard - the installer tells me I need to upgrade to OSX Lion

Comment: Code isn't manually compiled, its done on demand by invoking play run. Is there a way to force a recompile in Play! Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Removed Play Framework, downloaded a fresh copy and re-ran the app and it worked fine.  Old copy was restored from a backup so something may have gone awry there, but it's all good now.